# How to pick a process from the waitQueue to start running as soon as another specific process terminates

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, fork, wait, pid

I am writing a new system call that is equivalent to fork(), this system call will create two identical processes instead of one. then, it will start executing the first one right away, while the second one should be placed on hold, in a wait queue, until the first one terminates.

My questions are:
1- what function should I use to place a process in the wait queue?
I have found wait_event(wq, condition), but I cannot figure out the condition. also which waitQueue should I use? what are the choices and does it matter?

2- how can I trigger this waiting process to start executing as soon as the first fork terminates?
can I do it using signals?
or should I hook the exit system call and compare the pids?  I have already modified the task_struct and added additional variables to store the other process's id so that it is available for me to compare both of them.

Comment: Why do you need a new syscall for this? Can't you already do this from userspace with existing functions?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica it is just a learning experince. I am trying to learn more about the Linux kernel so I am trying to build a new version of fork that has its own syscall